# Paperclip Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm getting the following error in my development.log

[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream28514-0 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>

And i've googled about this error and i found out that many people have solved this by adding this line 
      Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"

However, i still get the same error even after adding that line! I've tried everything possible!

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Regards,

Punit

Comment: What operating system are you using? /usr/local/bin only makes sense on a unix-based system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Paperclip.options[:command_path] setting is for the location of your ImageMagick executables (in this case identify). Try running `which identify` and setting the option to be the directory that is returned. If that command doesn't return anything, make sure that ImageMagick is properly installed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.
which identify returns /usr/local/bin

Also i noticed something strange. The path /tmp/stream28514-0 is not valid. So the file is not getting saved. Does anyone know why this is happenning?

Comment: paperclip should remove the files after it is done processing them.
Could you try running identify from the command line? I had a similar problem recently when I upgraded ImageMagick and forgot to run ldconfig afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me...

I uninstalled the imagemagick that i installed from the official webpage.
I reinstalled it from sudo apt-get install imagemagick

then i did write Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "to/correct/path"

THE PROBLEM HERE WAS...

when i ran "which identify" it appearde that the path was "usr/local/bin/identify"
it means that we I was supposed to put as a path "usr/local/bin" as my path.

BUT IT DIDN'T WORKED!

I surprisingly found that i identify was also in the "usr/bin" path. So i changed:
"usr/local/bin" to **"usr/bin"**

And that was all!

Comment: I already had it installed, but reinstalling via `brew upgrade ImageMagick` fixed it for me.  Didn't even need the `command_path` option

Answer (score 3):

It means that it cannot find ImageMagick's executable `identify` on the location you specified in `Paperclip.options[:command_path]` (in your case `/usr/local/bin`).

This is tipically caused by two reason:

1. It might be that you actually did not installed ImageMagick.

   - **SOLUTION**: install it:

     - For MAC: `sudo port install ImageMagick` (which installs the binary release)
     - For UBUNTU: `sudo sudo apt-get install imagemagick`
2. It might be that the location where you installed ImageMagick is not `/usr/local/bin` but something else.

   - **SOLUTION**:  find where it is installed, or via the command:

     `which identify` (in case that identify is in the current PATH, as it should be)

   or via a raw find through the file system:

   `find / -name identify`

Anyway, the usual location for those file in Ubuntu should be `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems:

1. Image Magick is not installed or broken
2. Paperclip is not able to find Image Magick

Let's take them one at a time:

**1. Check you have Image Magick installed and it is working**

Type:

```
identify
```

at the command line, it should work. If it isn't found, or fails to work, install Image Magick. Did this fix it? If not, continue:

**2. Help Paperclip find Image Magick**

Type:

```
which identify
```

at the command line to get the path to the identify command. Now, in production.rb, add the following line to the configuration block:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

Restart your server. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

usr/bin worked me (Fedora 14 core)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the identify command in the command line and see if that gives you some error message. I found out that my server was missing some delegate libraries.

```
identify example.jpg
```