# Photo is not recognized by the 'identify' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip, development-environment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paperclip Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533351/paperclip-error)

I have ImageMagick installed. If I try using it on the command line it works. I can use identify. It is located in `/usr/bin`. And in my `development.rb` I do the

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/bin/'
```

It still will not work. I keep getting this error.

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h :file
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20121130-6368-1c4xwb9-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

I have no idea how to make this work. I have tried everything. I also tried adding this to my `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` but it didn't work

```
require 'paperclip'

if RAILS_ENV == "development"
 Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/bin/'
end
```

Comment: Presumably your `development.rb` should refer to `/usr/bin`, not `usr/bin`. Is that a typo in your `development.rb` file, or just in your question?

Comment: yea that is a typo in my question. I actually do have Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/bin/' in my development.rb. 
Sorry. What should I do?

Comment: Does `identify` process the file correctly in the first place on the command line?  Next. Upload the file and save it.  Don't process it.  Then try running identify on the command line on the uploaded file.  Seems like somewhere the file is getting corrupted/modified such that identify can't parse it.  It's finding it okay so I don't think settings :command_path is your issue.

Comment: Does `file <filename>` work from the command line?

Comment: So Identify just by itself works for the /tmp/stream20121130-6368-1c4xwb9-0.jpg. But I'm getting an error for 
identify -format "200x200" /tmp/stream20121130-6368-1c4xwb9-0.jpg.Why is that happening?

Comment: I had to downgrade to cocain 0.3.2. I was using 0.4.2. It works now. 
Thanks anyway